# Making a symbol image not filled on iOS versions below 15.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a TabView with labels, I am not sure why this isn't documented at all and I've found on another question on the stackoverflow that the following lines of code only works on iOS 15.0:

```swift
    if (selectedTab == 2) {
        Label("Playlist", systemImage: "star.fill")
    } else {
        Label("Playlist", systemImage: "star")
            .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
    }
```

This works as desired when my project has 15.0 as the minimum version, however, anything below marks the following error:

`Key path value type 'WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, SymbolVariants>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, SymbolVariants>`

How do I make earlier versions show unfilled icons (outline/default/none) in a TabView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it is the expected behaviour and it is documented.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolvariants) here. According to it `SymbolVariants` only available in `iOS 15 +` versions. So ur code will only work project has 15.0 as the minimum version and it will give the above error when a lower version is used.

What u can do is check the versions and add separate codes as below.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    if selectedTab == 2 {
        Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star.fill")
    } else {
        Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star")
            .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
    }
} else {
    if selectedTab == 2 {
        Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star.fill")
    } else {
        Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star")
    }
}
```

Comment: So using `Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star")` on pre-15.0 iOS will simply show the star symbol without the fill variant unless I explicitly mention it as "star.fill" ? I don't think I am able to test this currently but I'd like to confirm

Comment: yes there is an example in the documentation with heart image.  check it